# How to make multiple promises call

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

Hello I have to make multiple promises call but I got stuck, basically I get data from a socket service which communicate via modbus/TCP. I was able to communicate through a cordova plugin, but I have some problem grasping how promises work, here some code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init')
    this.getRegistrationNumber().then(() => {
      this.swVersionRequest()
    })    
  }

  getRegistrationNumber() {
    let self = this
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      self.socketService.getMatricola().then((data) => {
        self.registrationNumber = self.socketService.arrayBuffer2str(data.data.slice(3, data.data.length-2))
        console.log(`Registration number is ${self.registrationNumber}`)
        resolve()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  }

  swVersionRequest() {
    console.log("software version request");
      this.socketService.getSwVersion().then((data) => {
        this.softwareVersionWifiGsm = this.socketService.arrayBuffer2str(data.data.slice(3, data.data.length-2))
        this.softwareVersionWifiGsm = this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.substring(0, 2).split('').join(".") + ' ' + this.transformSwVersion(this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.substring(2, this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.length))
        console.log(`Software version is ${this.softwareVersionWifiGsm}`)
      })
  }

  getMachineType() {
    console.log('get machine type')
    this.socketService.getMachineType().then((data) => {
      this.machineType = data.data.slice(4, data.data.length-2)
      console.log(`Machine type is ${this.machineType}`)
    })
  }

  refreshData() {    
    this.getRegistrationNumber().then(() => {
      this.swVersionRequest()
    })
    .then(() => { // not working like this
      this.getMachineType()
    })
  }

  transformSwVersion(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/, "$1/$2/$3")
  }
```

then when I get the machineType I'd like to check the response from the promise like this maybe:

```
if (this.machineType == 2) {
   callSoftwareVersionB() // another promise
} else {
   callSoftwareVersionC() // another promise
}
```

I don't know if it's clear

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand all of your question but your problem seems related only to Promises.

If you want to chain your Promises, you have to return the resolve*(with your data here*) like this :

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  return self.socketService.getMatricola().then((data) => {
    self.registrationNumber = self.socketService.arrayBuffer2str(data.data.slice(3, data.data.length-2))
    console.log(`Registration number is ${self.registrationNumber}`)
    return resolve(withYourDataHere)
  })
```

After that, you will be able to chain your promise and get the result like this :

```
getRegistrationNumber().then((yourData) => {
  console.log(yourData);
  return yourData;
});
```

If you don't need the previous response to execute the next requests, you can perform a Promise.all().

For example you can do that :

```
const promises = [];
promises.push(getRegistrationNumber());
promises.push(getMachineType());
//etc...
return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  //your code will be executed after all your requests are resolved
})
```

In your case :

```
refreshData() {    
   this.getRegistrationNumber().then(() => {
     this.swVersionRequest()
   })
   .then(() => { // not working like this
     this.getMachineType()
   })
 }
```

this code becomes :

```
swVersionRequest() {
    console.log("software version request");
      return this.socketService.getSwVersion().then((data) => {
        this.softwareVersionWifiGsm = this.socketService.arrayBuffer2str(data.data.slice(3, data.data.length-2))
        this.softwareVersionWifiGsm = this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.substring(0, 2).split('').join(".") + ' ' + this.transformSwVersion(this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.substring(2, this.softwareVersionWifiGsm.length))
        console.log(`Software version is ${this.softwareVersionWifiGsm}`)
      })
}

getMachineType() {
    console.log('get machine type')
    return this.socketService.getMachineType().then((data) => {
      console.log(`Machine type is ${this.machineType}`)
      return this.machineType = data.data.slice(4, data.data.length-2)
    })
}

refreshData() {    
   return this.getRegistrationNumber().then(() => {
     return this.swVersionRequest().then(() => {
       return this.getMachineType() //you can chain that if you change the return in your function
     })
   })
}
```

OR

```
refreshData() {  
      const promises = [];
      promises.push(this.getRegistrationNumber());
      promises.push(this.swVersionRequest());
      promises.push(this.getMachineType());
      return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
         //type your code here
      })
    }
```

I'm agree with saglamcem, you have all the documentation needed to do that on MDN and you can use Observables also.

Hope we help you.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this too. Be patient, I'm still learning :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

I Highly Recommend you some pretty simple examples how the promises works, just to understand how the Promises Works.

- [TypeScript Promises Examples](https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-es-6-typescript-promises-examples/)
- [(Google Developers) - JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)

As you can see Promises is always the better option to handle the most of SYNC problems(that is basically the problem that you have there :) ), later you can start to see libs as [RXJS - Angular](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library)  to start solving those problems.

> **Advice:** Is always cool make some review of basics concepts, to understand the high level implementations of some libs. And because is cool learn, or remember things that we learn long time ago! Feel free to ask anything! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Angular, I would suggest you use [rxjs Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) instead of Promises. Observables are not the easiest concept to grasp, but they are quite powerful.

If you would like to keep going with promises, the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax could be helpful (instead of getting lost in .then().then() statements).

To answer the "multiple promise call" question;

- If your requests don't depend on the responses of other requests, you can run them together using the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) functionality.
- If your requests depend on the result of previous requests, looking into the async/await documentation from MDN (already linked) can be quite helpful.

Let me know if I can help with anything. Good luck. :)

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. I was thinking about observables with RxJS, and I would like to try them cause I will refactor this part of code. How would I use promiseAll in this case? Or if you can show me how to use observables in this case would be great. Thank you

Comment: @sebba23 ClementRsln's answer seems inclusive, so my kind advice would be to (as vdsancheza pointed out) start by learning the basics well enough, and moving forward with Observables. I'd definitely learning more on Observables, as Angular uses rxjs (and so observables) internally. Go step by step, at your own pace, and after having a clear understanding of promises, you can choose your path. :) Good luck!